# l2ping bluetooth not timing out fast enough

Tags: pi-3, bluetooth, bash

I have been experimenting with pinging a list of known Bluetooth MAC addresses for a tracking project with a Pi 3, however, the ping does not seem to time out until after 5-7 seconds if there is no device detected. In contrast if there is a device it will only take around 1 second before it moves on. Even with -t there seems to be no overriding it.

```
sudo l2ping -c 1 -t 1 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
```

Is there any way to force a faster timeout?

EDIT: Corrected flag order

Comment: usually arguments go before the final address. from l2ping usage: l2ping [-i device] [-s size] [-c count] [-t timeout] [-d delay] [-f] [-r] [-v] <bdaddr>         so maybe try 'sudo l2ping -t 1 -c 1 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx

Comment: I've tried 'sudo l2ping -c 1 -t 1 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx' and 'sudo l2ping -t 1 -c 1 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx' as well now, both take ~7 seconds still to execute, but thanks for catching that.